# Can't execute installed gem `erb2slim` using rbenv

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rbenv, slim-lang

I just installed a gem called `erb2slim` and it does have an executable with the same name. However, after installing I'm told that there is no executable by that name.

Here's what I've done:

```
rbenv version       
    2.5.3 (set by /Users/.../.ruby-version)

gem uninstall erb2slim
   Successfully uninstalled erb2slim-0.0.1

gem install erb2slim  

    Fetching: erb2slim-0.0.1.gem (100%)
    Successfully installed erb2slim-0.0.1
    1 gem installed

erb2slim
    rbenv: erb2slim: command not found

    The `erb2slim' command exists in these Ruby versions:
      2.1.2
      2.2.1
```

I did try to execute it by adding it to the Gemfile and executing it from there like so:

```
bundle exec erb2slim
```

But I got the same error.

Comment: Have you tried the `html2slim` gem? Both are very old, but one might work for you.  Which version of ruby are you using?

Comment: I'm using 2.5.3 using rbenv. `html2slim` does work so far but I have to check with my setup.

Comment: @jad You were right. Installing the `html2slim` gem will also setup the `erb2slim` executable. You may add an answer and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try the alternative provided by html2slim:

https://rubygems.org/gems/html2slim/versions/0.2.0

This should provide a `erb2slim` executable as well as an `html2slim` executable